# Cordova Browser Screen Limitations

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to use Cordova in-app browser in a limited area so I can put custom buttons. I tried iframe. I looked at the official documentation. I tried CSS injection.
Where should I look?

Answer (score -1):

You can just use an iframe pointed at the URL instead.